# regex to split a string into float/number and string

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I split the following using regex.

```
'abcd1234567ef' into 'abcd', '1234567', 'ef'
'abcd1234567.89ef' into 'abcd', '1234567.89', 'ef'
```

I need to split a string in Postgres SQL which may or may not have decimal numbers.
I have tried this `SELECT regexp_match('abcd1234567ef', '(?:(.*?)(\d+)(.*)){1,1}');` from the Postgres document, works only for the first case.

EDIT: After getting that working with rewritten's answer, There were some columns which have data in the form
`'abcd12efg34567hij'`
which needs to be split as either
`'abcd', '12, 'efg', '34567', 'hij'` or
`'abcd', '12efg', '34567', 'hij'`.
Either will work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dot, otherwise it means "any character".

The regexp to match and capture the numeric part is is:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Notice the optional "dot and digits" that is grouped with a non-capturing pair of parentheses.

To match one substring, you can use `regexp_match`, if you have multiple substrings you will need `regexp_matches(data, regexp, 'g')` that will return multiple rows. If you need one row only, combine with `ARRAY_AGG`.

The example `abcd12efg34567hij` will give:

```sql
SELECT regexp_matches('abcd12efg34567hij', '\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 'g')

12
34567

SELECT array_agg(regexp_matches('abcd12efg34567hij', '\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 'g')

{12, 34567}
```

If you need also the intermediate pieces, you need to use many more capturing groups:

```
([^\d]*)(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([^\d]*))*
```

```
([^\d]*) // group 1 non-digits
        (?: // non-capturing group
           (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) // group 2, 4, 6, … digits with one dot
                          ([^\d]*) // group 3, 5, 7, … non-digits
                                  )* // end group, repeat 0 or more times
```

(spaces, newlines and coments added for clarity, they should not be in the regexp)

Comment: if you can help once more, after getting that working, some columns have data in the form 'abcd12efg34567hij' which needs to be split as either 'abcd', '12, 'efg', '34567', 'hij' or 'abcd', '12efg', '34567', 'hij'. either will work for me.

Comment: You should ask a separate question, with a list of test cases, so it will be easier to answer

Comment: Just added the part to the question.

Comment: Answered in edit

Comment: SELECT (regexp_matches('abcd12efg34567hij', '(?:(.*?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)){1,1}', 'g')) gives {abcd,12,efg34567hij} needs to be either 'abcd', '12, 'efg', '34567', 'hij' or 'abcd', '12efg', '34567', 'hij'. 
SELECT (regexp_matches('abcd1234567hij', '(?:(.*?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)){1,1}', 'g')) give correctly {abcd,1234567,hij}

Comment: So you need all the pieces, then you need to use groupings and repetitions, as you suggest, but the problem with your regexp is that you limit the mathes to 1. I will update the response.